# How to put a notice on GitHub releases page?

Tags: github

A project I'm involved with wants to do releases only via PyPI and never puts releases in the "Releases" section on their GitHub repo. Is there a way to put a banner or other notice *on the `/releases` page itself* , to help point visitors in the right direction and alleviate confusion about the apparent lack of releases of the software? The README file can explain where people should go for releases, but people can still miss the information, especially if they have gotten used to reflexively clicking on the releases link on GitHub repos.

I've read the [GitHub documentation about releases](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-releases) but did not find something suitable, nor do I see anything suitable in the repository settings section.

Comment: GitHub releases are essentially glorified git tags. The README is likely the best place since it's in a central location and is easy to locate since it displays by default on the landing page. If you're already using tags, then users going to the releases page will see tags without all the extra descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to put a "shifting tag" (meaning, a tag regularly put on the latest master HEAD) called:

```
See_README_releases_only_on_PyPi
```

That way, the empty Release page would at least displays tags, starting with that most recent one.